# Need help using tasklist to check if the Battle.net process

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10, tasklist

I am trying to create a batch file as an impromptu shortcut to launch the Battle.net client and when it fully opens, to launch Hearthstone specifically but i'm sure it can be applied to any Blizzard game.

The problem is when I run

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Hearthstone\Hearthstone Beta Launcher.exe"
tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq battle.net.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "battle.net.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" echo Battle net is ready
```

And if that worked then I would use `start "" "battlenet://WTCG"` but it immediately echos even though nothing is visible on my screen and the process is not running in task manager.  Which means it would try to launch hearthstone without Battle.net being open even though the script says it is.

Is this just an issue with Battle.net processes or am I doing something very wrong?  I am currently using Windows 10 if it matters.